# npm run dev not working in nextjs project

Tags: npm, next.js

I am learning nextjs ...does `npx create-next-app@latest` to create my project name "mynext" ..
then i run `npm run dev` but it only showing

> mynext@0.1.0 dev

> next dev

and then again this

PS C:\Users\User\mynext>

my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "mynext",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "next": "13.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.5.4"
  }
}
```

so help me to run my first nextjs project

i already updated my node version to v18.18.0
windows 10 32bit

Comment: can you provide more details/screenshots of what happens when you run npm run dev? There can be different reasons as to why your project is not loading, e.g it may be that the default port it runs on (i.e 3000) is already in use, etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next Js development server is not starting after running "npm run dev"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77013157/next-js-development-server-is-not-starting-after-running-npm-run-dev)

Comment: when i am ruuning "npm run dev" it not showing any error but only this > mynext@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

Comment: done everything in my knowledge didn't work...and the worst part is that it not showing any error but not working also